# How to create lists template enfold?

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, editor, jetpack

I am using wordpress to create the website, I have two problems, the

**First:** I cannot create menus"can't customize drop down menu", after saving the menu it disappears.

**Second:** I can't add an image in Fullwidth Easy Slider. About placing and saving the image, it does not appear on the page. Note that I am using an infold template.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSrR0.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whDXw.png)

Also I use Jetpack plugin
Website address https://ikelvinator.com/
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SofW2.png)

I bought a new template called enfold from Envato, reset all settings.

Comment: Please contact the vendor for your support options, see as well:  [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746). And   welcome to Stack Overflow (SO), which works by asking one question at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have installed and activated all necessary plugins for your template. In case you encounter any issues, you can use the ["wp reset"](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-reset/) plugin to reset all settings to their default state. After that, set up everything again from scratch, and it should function flawlessly.

Please provide some screenshots if you are facing specific problems so that I can better understand the issues you are encountering.